# Decorate method on found for LazyList Apache commons

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I have imported apache commons lib for my spring boot project in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
<version>4.4</version>
```

Have imported below package as well in model file.

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.FactoryUtils;
```

Here is the code where I am trying to use LazyList from Apache io.

```
private List<Children> childrens = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<Children>(),FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Children.class));
```

I have imported LazyList from Apache commons, But STS is not able to recognize decorate() from LazyList.

Please find below error.

```
The method decorate(ArrayList<Children>, FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Children.class)) is undefined for the type LazyList
```

Need quick help can someone please assist me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the API has changed significantly between version 3 and version 4.  In v4 you want to use the method

```
static <E> LazyList<E>  lazyList(List<E> list, Factory<? extends E> factory)
```

instead.